# ApplicationContext.xml bean execution - How?

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I've `applicationContext.xml` which contains below line:

```
<bean id="myclass" class="com.abc.myclassinfo" >
</bean>
```

And, myclassinfo.java has below code:

```
public class myclassinfo {
   public myclassinfo() {
       // Here I'm initializing Jersey client
   }
}
```

Now, what happens when spring loads the `applicationContext.xml`? Does it invoke this constructor?

Also, if I want to insitialize the Jersey client some other way without `applicationContext.xml`, how do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, spring calls the constructor.  If you do not specify any construtor args then it will call the no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, it calls the constructor (the no-arg one by default, or another one if annotated)
- Then it calls a `@PostConstruct` / `init-method`
- Then it calls postprocessors that can manipulate the object further

IF you want to use the class outside spring, you just instantiate it (using the constructor), and manually invoke the init method (if such exists). Note that you lose the automatic proxies that spring creates around your objects for transactions, scheduling, caching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `init-method` or `@Postconstruct` annotation for init  some logic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a log statement would have cleared up the first question pretty quickly.

Your second question isn't totally clear to me. You can use annotations, and skip at least most XML. I'm not aware that the Jersey client stuff has a hard dependency on Spring, however.

If you want to use Spring without a config file and without annotations, you can build a context programmatically, although I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, except possible for testing. Even then, it's easier to just extend an existing context, IMO.